# fuse allow_root is not set - why files in user mount is seen via sudo?

Tags: namespace, fuse

Why root can see user files when `allow_root` is not set by `fuse`? (user2 get `permission denied` for `ls /media/user1/Data`, but can see files via `sudo`, Linux Mint 19).

```
user2@PC:~$ cat /etc/fuse.conf
...
# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
#user_allow_other

user2@PC:~$ mount 
...
/dev/sda5 /media/user1/Data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

user2@PC:~$ man fuse
...
   allow_other
          This option overrides the security measure restricting  file  access  to  the  user
          mounting the filesystem.  So all users (including root) can access the files.  This
          option is by default only allowed to root, but this restriction can be removed with
          a configuration option described in the previous section.

user2@PC:~$ ls /media/user1/Data
ls: cannot access '/media/user1/Data': Permission denied


user2@PC:~$ sudo -i
# ls /media/user1/Data
...list of files
```

Comment: You asked about allow_root or allow_other?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 allow_root. neither is set, allow_root afaiu man page is needed to allow access for root.